# cakephp mapping $belongsTo association to a non primary key

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I was told that to accomplish mapping the $belongsTo to a non primary key, I would set the foreignKey to false and set the conditions by someone on another forum (IRC, actually).  However, I don't think I'm doing this correctly.  Below is my $belongsTo code I was trying:

```
var $belongsTo = array(

    'Inventory' => array(
        'className'    => 'Inventory',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => array('RentalLineitem.i_num' => 'Inventory.i_num'),
        'dependent'    => false
    )

);
```

When I look at the SQL query that's being generated, the ON clause in the JOIN is looking for the string value instead of the column:  `RentalLineitem`.`i_num` = 'Inventory.i_num' instead of what I need which is `RentalLineitem`.`i_num` = `Inventory`.`i_num`.

I've been told to change the "just change the database schema" to be correct.  However, this is a legacy application, the database already has existed for 10 years, and there are other applications using this database.  I HAVE to work with the tables I have, and I can not change the schema.

How can I properly associate these models?

Comment: Yeah this doesn't appear to be correct. Just so I don't post any assumptions in my answer, are you attempting to relate the `Inventory` model to the `RentalLineItem` model?  I'd assume that you are trying to say `Inventory` belongs to `RentalLineItem`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

hmm this might not be the correct way, but i already had some similar problems and i corrected it by doing something like:

```
'conditions' => array(' `RentalLineitem`.`i_num` = `Inventory`.`i_num`'),
```

hope this helps,

Good Luck

Comment: that was awesome, it is working great.  Thank you for your response.  I've been struggling with this, and the folks on IRC have just been bashing me about a SQL Schema I had no control over. People should understand that sometimes as developers we have no control over integral parts of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You just edit in conditions like that:

```
'conditions' => array(
  'RentalLineitem.i_num = Inventory.i_num',
),
```

It works correctly in my case.